# App crashing on screen rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation

My app keeps crashing when I rotate the screen.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
06-24 14:43:29.531  25869-25869/com.rcd.mypr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rcd.mypr, PID: 25869
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rcd.mypr/com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsActivity.onCreate(WorkoutsActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsFragment did not create a view.
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4826)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
            at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsActivity.onCreate(WorkoutsActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is WorkoutsActivity onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workouts);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);

        // fragment is bodyFragment
        fragment = new WorkoutsFragment();
        benchmarkFragment = new TheBenchmarkGirlsListFragment();

        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.workoutsListFragment, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT_HEROES)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Here is my WorkoutsFragment which is creating the list of workouts

```
package com.rcd.mypr.Workouts;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.rcd.mypr.R;

public class WorkoutsFragment extends Fragment {

    WorkoutsDatabaseHelper db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ListView listContent;
    Cursor cursor;
    private Context mContext;
    WorkoutsAdapter workoutsAdapter;

    public WorkoutsFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getActivity();
        db = new WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(mContext);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workouts_list, container, false);

        listContent = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create the Adapter
        workoutsAdapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(mContext, cursor);

        // Set the adapter to ListView
        listContent.setAdapter(workoutsAdapter);


        return rootView;
    }


    private void initViews() {
        //Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");
    }

    private void addItemsToList() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getWorkoutNames();
        Log.d("history.java", "finished Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();");
        String[] from = {"workouts_name"};
        int[] to = {R.id.tv_label};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.fragment_workouts_list_single_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    /*public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        workoutsAdapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(mContext, cursor);
        listContent.setAdapter(workoutsAdapter);

    }*/

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }


}
```

activity_workouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/workoutsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsFragment" ></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_workouts_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkGray">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

I think it has something to do with the activity_workouts.xml

I tried changing that to just a FrameLayout with no fragment and it still loads the list, but will still crash on rotate.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed activity_workouts.xml from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/workoutsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsFragment" ></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/workoutsListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```